# Change Value Prior to Submit

Tags: php, jquery, quill

I am using [quilljs](https://quilljs.com/) to allow users to essentially create HTML that will be rendered to other users as an alert. The markup for my form is quite simple, it is the following.

But, whenever the user hits the submit button, I want the post value of *message* to include the HTML generated by quilljs. Am I able to do this via JavaScript/jQuery, PHP, or some other method?

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('date').setAttribute('min', yyyy_mm_dd(new Date()));
}
function yyyy_mm_dd(d) { return d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var quill = new Quill('.quill-editor', {
    modules: { toolbar: true },
    placeholder: 'Attention: This is a very important message ...',
    theme: 'snow'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.4/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>New Alerts</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <div class="form-control quill-editor" id="message" name="message" style="min-height: 8rem;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Display Until</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('#your_form_id').on('submit',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //Get form data here. Change the values. Submit new data with Ajax });`

Comment: Bear in mind that all the work QuillJs does is to convert your edits to the displayed HTML that gets put in the users screen. Yes, it updates the DOM, check the code in your browsers inspector.

That means that $('.quill-editor').html() is always what's on your screen (using jQuery syntax).